# how to change the apt-cache version for python-setuptools on ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, caching, ubuntu

Running:

sudo apt-get install python-setuptools

on Ubuntu generates an error which looks like the apt cache is telling apt-get to try to read an old version that no longer exists on the remote distribution site.

Looking at the remote distribution site, I can see the newer .deb files, but not the 0.6.15.

How can the apt cache version be updated to point to a version number that exists on the distribution site?

The error message in full is:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-setuptools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 217 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,077 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main python-setuptools all 0.6.15-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/distribute/python-setuptools_0.6.15-1ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

makes downloads a list of updated packages!